# CakePHP retrieve data from another Model

Tags: php, cakephp, model

I am new to cakephp and I have a little problem about retrieving data from another model.

My table association is like this:

```
Items hasMany Stocks

Stocks belongsTo Items

Items belongsTo UnitMeasurement

UnitMeasurement hasMany Items
```

My problem is I want to show UnitMeasurement Name to Stocks index html table view.

Current Html table view:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Item           | Stock Balance|          Unit          |     Created |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Microprocessor |    12        | DISPLAY UNIT NAME HERE!| 19/1/2014   |
Microcontroller|    20        | DISPLAY UNIT NAME HERE!| 19/1/2014   |             
CPU            |    12        | DISPLAY UNIT NAME HERE!| 19/1/2014   |             
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How do I make the succesful query ?

Thanks.

EDIT:

This is my find query in my StocksController index function:

```
public function index() {
        $this->Stock->recursive = 0;
        $order = "Stock.id DESC";
        //set orderby
        $stock = $this->Stock->find('all',array('order'=>$order));
        $this->set('stocks', $stock);

        //query to find UnitMeasurement Name for Stocks Item
        foreach ($stock as $stocks) {
            //debug($stocks);
            $this->loadModel('Items');
            $unitMeasurement = $this->Items->find('first',array('fields'=>'unit_measurement_id','conditions'=>array('Items.id'=>$stocks['Stock']['item_id'])));
            $this->set('units',$unitMeasurement);
        }

    }
```

Thanks again.

Comment: can you paste your find query? applying find on which model ?

Answer (score 0):

check this model name always singular please check and let me know if it works !

```
foreach ($stock as $stocks) {
            //debug($stocks);
            //$this->loadModel('Items');
            $this->loadModel('Item');
            $unitMeasurement = $this->Item->find('first',array('fields'=>'unit_measurement_id','conditions'=>array('Item.id'=>$stocks['Stock']['item_id'])));
            $this->set('units',$unitMeasurement);
        }
```

Comment: it's worked.but it returned an ID of the UnitMeasurement instead of name. How do I view the name and if stock doesn't have UnitMeasurement   it should not return the Unit name?

Comment: or should I make another table contained an column of unit_id and stock_id ?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a query like this:

```
$items = $this->Item->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Item.name',
        'SUM(Stock.amount) as amount',
        'UnitMeasurement.name',
        'Item.created',
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => "stocks",
            'alias' => "Stock",
            'conditions' => "Item.id = Stock.item_id"
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'unit_measurements',
            'alias' => 'UnitMeasurement',
            'conditions' => 'UnitMeasurement.id = Item.unit_measurement_id',
        ),      
    ),
    'group' => array('Item.id', 'Item.unit_measurement_id'),
));
```